# What is an example of a situation that uses the kinematic equations that isn't motion through space?

Tags: derivatives, mathematical-modeling, economics, kinematics

The kinematic equations describe the relationship between a variable $x$ and its first $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and second $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ derivatives, assuming its second derivative is constant. This does not nessecarily bind it to the translational or rotational motion it describes in classical mechanics.

My question is do you have any good examples of something (not physics related) that can be modeled using the kinematic equations? I've been trying to think of some sort of economic example (x is money supply, v is rate of new money, etc.) but I don't know enough about economics to make it work.

*An aside: I posted this on the physics stack exchange but it was removed because it was too broad. Upon further consideration, I think this was fair as the question isn't about physics per se. What I'm really asking for is an example of a real world system modeled by a constant 2nd derivative.*

Answer (score 1):

The random-walk hypotheses for the evolution of consumption over time (i.e. only unexpected income shocks have an effect on consumption) is derived under the assumption that utility is quadratic $$u(c) = c-\frac{a}{2}c^2,$$ which implies a constant second derivative ($u''(c)=a$).